# A ring homomorphism over rational numbers is the identity

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ring-homomorphism

Let $f : \mathbb{Q} → \mathbb{Q}$ be a ring homomorphism. Show that f is the identity.

Im having trouble with this problem. I started considering two elements in $\mathbb{Q}$ and the definition of ring homomorphism:

Let $x, y \in \mathbb{Q}$ such that $x = \frac{m}{n}, y=\frac{m'}{n'}$with $m,m',n,n'\in \mathbb{Z}$ then:

$f(\frac{m}{n}*\frac{m'}{n'}) = f(\frac{m}{n})*f(\frac{m'}{n'})$

and

$f(\frac{m}{n}+\frac{m'}{n'}) = f(\frac{mn'+m'n}{nn'})=f(\frac{m}{n})+f(\frac{m'}{n'})$

Clearly, my goal is to show that:

$f(\frac{m}{n}*\frac{m'}{n'}) =\frac{m}{n}*\frac{m'}{n'}$

or

$f(\frac{m}{n}+\frac{m'}{n'}) =\frac{m}{n}+\frac{m'}{n'}$

I've been thinking for like an hour and still achieve nothing, any ideas/hints?

Comment: First, prove that $f(a)=a$ for all integers $a$. Then prove that $f(a/b)=a/b$ for integers $a$, $b$ with $b$ nonzero.

Comment: First show that $f$ is the identity when restricted tp $\mathbb{Z}^{+}$.

Comment: Alternatively, consider ker f, which is an ideal of Q. But Q is field so ker f = 0 or Q itself. What does this imply?

Comment: Hint: use the $f(1 + \dots + 1) = f(1) + \dots + f(1)$ trick.

Comment: For rings with unity, a homomorphism should satisfy $f(1)=1$.

Comment: [related](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/175477/if-f-mathbb-q-to-mathbb-q-is-a-homomorphism-prove-that-fx-0-for-all-x)

Answer (score 1):

Another way to see the answers above (which are all fine) is the following :
Let $f$ be the ring morphism in question. For your question to be true, it has to be that you only allow $f(1)=1$ in your definition of ring morphism. Therefore that's what I will assume. So $f$ is also a field morphism.

Consider $R=\{x\in \Bbb{Q}\mid f(x) = x\}$. Then quite obviously, $R$ is not empty ($1,0\in R$) and it is closed under addition and multiplication and taking inverses for non-zero elements.

Therefore $R$ is a subfield of $\Bbb{Q}$.

But $\Bbb{Q}$ is a prime field and thus its only subfield is itself. Therefore $R=\Bbb{Q}$, and $f$ is the identity.

There are two advantages of this answer over the others : 1- it can be applied to any prime field, that is, the $\Bbb{F}_p$ for prime $p$, and $\Bbb{Q}$; 2- if you have already proved that $\Bbb{Q}$ is a prime field, then it can allow you not to redo the calculations that are done in other answers (but at some point you will have to do them)

Answer (score 0):

Consider $f(1)$.  We have

$(f(1))^2 = f(1)f(1) = f(1 \cdot 1) = f(1), \tag{1}$

or

$f(1)(f(1) - 1) = 0, \tag{2}$

whence, if $f(1) \ne 0$, yields

$f(1) = 1. \tag{3}$

If $f(1) = 0, \tag{4}$

then for any $r \in \Bbb Q$,

$f(r) = f(r \cdot 1) = f(r)f(1) = f(r) \cdot 0 = 0, \tag{5}$

that is, $f:\Bbb Q \to \Bbb Q$ is the trivial homomorphism, which we set aside.  Thus we look at the case (3).  For any $n \in \Bbb Z_+ = \{z \in \Bbb Z: z > 0 \}$, we have

$f(n) = n, \tag{6}$

as may be seen by a simple induction:  if

$f(k) = k, \tag{7}$

then

$f(k + 1) = f(k) + f(1) = f(k) + 1 = k + 1; \tag{8}$

thus $f$ fixes all of $\Bbb Z_+$.  Also, for any $q \in \Bbb Q$,

$f(0) + f(q) = f(0 + q) = f(q), \tag{9}$

so

$f(0) = 0; \tag{10}$

if $m \in \Bbb Z_- = \{z \in \Bbb Z: z < 0 \}$, then

$f(m) + f(-m) = f(m + (-m)) = f(0) = 0, \tag{11}$

so

$f(m) = -f(-m) = -(-m) = m, \tag{12}$

where we have used the fact that $-m \in \Bbb Z_+$, hence is fixed by $f$.
(12) shows that $f$ fixes $\Bbb Z_-$ as well; by (6), (10), and (12) we see that $f$ fixes all of $\Bbb Z$.  Now if

$\dfrac{p}{q} \in \Bbb Q, \tag{13}$

where $p, q \in \Bbb Z$, $q \ne 0$, then

$q \cdot \dfrac{p}{q} = p, \tag{14}$

so

$q \cdot f(\dfrac{p}{q}) = f(q) \cdot f(\dfrac{p}{q}) = f(q \cdot \dfrac{p}{q}) = f(p) = p, \tag{14}$

whence

$f(\dfrac{p}{q}) = \dfrac{p}{q}; \tag{15}$

that is, $f$ fixes $\Bbb Q$, element-wise.

Answer (score 0):

A nonzero *group* homomorphism $f\colon\mathbb{Q}\to\mathbb{Q}$ is surjective.

Indeed, suppose $f(x)=a/b\ne0$. Then $f(bx)=a$, so consider $y=bx/a$; we have
$$
af(bx/a)=f(abx/a)=f(bx)=a
$$
and therefore $f(bx/a)=1$, because $\mathbb{Q}$ is torsionfree. Set $bx/a=y$ and choose $m/n\in\mathbb{Q}$ (so $n\ne0$). Then
$$
nf(my/n)=f(my)=mf(y)=m=n\frac{m}{n}
$$
Again this implies $f(my/n)=m/n$.

In your particular case, you can choose $y=1$. Thus $f(m/n)=m/n$.